# How to edit a whole keyframe axis

Tags: animation, camera, keyframes

I was creating animated camera and wanted to rotate the z-axis in 90 degrees.
I don't want to do the whole animation again, so is there a way?

[image]

Comment: You can parent Camera to Empty and rotate the empty :)

Comment: thanks that worked!